# React: Array inside object doesn't get replaced after updating object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an object `firstOccurrence` that contains an array `extras`, which I set to an empty array initially. I then do an AJAX request and replace the entire object `firstOccurrence`, which works fine with the exception of the array not being replaced and remaining empty.

How can I replace the entire object including the array?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Job extends Component {
  state = {
    firstOccurrence: {
      customer: {},
      job: {},
      extras: []
    }
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(
      `http://api.test.dev:5000/jobs/1.json`,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Token token=123' }
      }
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        firstOccurrence: response.data
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.firstOccurrence.customer.firstName} {this.state.firstOccurrence.customer.lastName}</Text>
        </View>
        {this.state.firstOccurrence.extras.length > 0 &&
          <View>
            <Text>Extras: {this.state.firstOccurrence.extras}</Text>
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

JSON response:

[image]

Comment: Can you post up the JSON response data?

Comment: @Pineda I've added it to the question

Comment: What is your expected output and what happens instead?

Comment: @Pineda I'll delete this question, it had to do with the API not responding and React rendering outdated data. Thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the request in the function `componentDidMount` instead of the constructor:

```
 constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      firstOccurrence: {
        customer: {},
        job: {},
        extras: []
      }
    };
 }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(
      `http://api.test.dev:5000/crew/v1/jobs/1.json`          
    ).then(response => {this.setState({
      firstOccurrence: response.data
    })});
  }
```

It [will be called when the component is mounted](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and you'll be able to set the state there and trigger a re-render. You should bear in mind that `firstOccurrence` will have the initial value you set in the constructor in the first render, and then the component will be re-rendered when the API call finishes and the new value is set.

Comment: I moved the AJAX request out of the constructor but it still doesn't work